# ExceptionInInitializerError when calling method from a Object

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I'm trying to call a method from my object with Class.forName but I've got java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

```
class MainClass(implicit val executionContex: ExecutionContext, usersDAO: UsersDAO){

  def findUser(user: User): Future[Option[User]] = {
    usersDAO.find(user)
  }

}
```

//    and I want to call my function

```
  val myClass = Class.forName("MainClass").newInstance().asInstanceOf[MainClass]

 //  myClass.findUser(User(0,"a", "a", "a"))
```

> [info] Done packaging.
>
> [info] Running com.base.app.WebServer
>
> [error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> [error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> [error] at com.base.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.scala)
>
> [error] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: Please maintain the format of your post.

Comment: @Zaur Nerimanli I am not sure why are you not creating an object using new, val object = new MainClass(param1, param2)
object.findUser(user)

Comment: @MaheshChandKandpal
when I'm trying to create this way, I should assign params, but if use class.forName I should not use assign params

Comment: @Sanip I didn't understand you :|

Comment: val myClass = new MainClass {
    //override def find(user: User): Future[Option[User]] = ???
  }
I should override my function again, and if I write it, it will make uncounted iteration, process willl kill

Answer (score 0):

> when I'm trying to create this way, I should assign params, but if use class.forName I should not use assign params

`Class.forName("MainClass").newInstance()` is equivalent to `new MainClass()` without parameters, if that constructor doesn't exist the call will fail. And for the class you show this constructor doesn't exist. Java reflection also doesn't have any idea about implicit parameters so you have to supply them explicitly (and Scala reflection isn't much better).

So yes, you do need to pass the parameters to create an instance, just in a different and less type-safe way:

```
Class.forName("MainClass").getConstructors()(0).newInstance(param1, param2).asInstanceOf[MainClass]
```

Also note that the parameter of `forName` is the fully qualified class name, i.e. it should be not just `"MainClass"` but `"your.package.MainClass"`.

Comment: hmmm, so, How can I call my method placed in class by in other object?

Comment: I have tried trait and extend
abstract class and extend, after these I have tried to write new MainClass, but I can't get the excepted result :(

Comment: "How can I call my method placed in class by in other object?" Without supplying constructor parameters? You can't, period. I especially don't see why you'd expect it to be possible when `findUser` needs `usersDAO`, but it wouldn't be possible anyway.

Comment: Nothing stops you from writing `new MainClass()(null, null) { override def find(user: User): Future[Option[User]] = ... }` if you really need it and don't have implicit `ExecutionContext` and `UsersDAO` in scope. But why would you want it?